# Yii2 skip to other URL route if <controller>/<action> is not found

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a custom URL route for a controller action i.e:

```
['pattern'=>'<username>/<post_slug>', 'route'=>'post/view'],
```

Entering something like `localhost/thisismyname/my-user-post` would call `post/view` with the `username` and `post_slug` parameters as intended.

The issue with this route is that all my other controller actions no longer work. `localhost/post/index` would call `post/view` with the parameters `post` as `username` and `index` as `post_slug`.

Is there an efficient way to give priority to `<controller>/</action>` URLs, and if there's no said `<controller>/<action>` it would pass the parameters as `<username>/<post_slug>` to the `post/view` URL route?

I don't want to create a separate route like `site/<controller>/<action>` or manually add every controller & action as a route into the URL Manager since both are ugly workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule that you specify is very ambigous, so almost any route match it.

You can write a [urlRule class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rules) and check, is the route `<username>/<post_slug>` route or not.

As another solution you can place this rule at the very end of your urlManager's rules configuration array.